# Add Line Break In Error Message

Tags: apex, error-messages, adderror, line-break

The below code builds an error message displaying the values from multiple records (typically 12).

```
Map<String,Budget__c> budgetByIdentifier = new Map<String,Budget__c>([SELECT Identifier__c, Id
                                                                        FROM Budget__c
                                                                       WHERE Identifier__c IN :budgetIdentifiers]);

            for(Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c mrf : newMRFs) {
                mrfOppId = mrf.Opportunity__c;
                mrfTeamName = teamByOppId.get(mrfOppId);
                mrfProductName = productByOppId.get(mrfOppId);
                try {
                    budgetId = budgetByIdentifier.get(mrfTeamName + '-' + mrfProductName + '-' + mrf.Revenue_Date__c.month() + '-' + mrf.Revenue_Date__c.year() ).Id;
                    mrf.Budget__c = budgetId;
                } catch(NullPointerException e) {
                    existingMessage = errorMessagebyOppId.get(mrfOppId);
                    if (existingMessage != null) {
                        errorMessagebyOppId.put(mrfOppId, existingMessage +  ' Team Name ' + mrfTeamName + ', Product Name ' + mrfProductName + ' & Revenue Date ' + mrf.Revenue_Date__c.format());
                    }
                    else {
                        errorMessagebyOppId.put(mrfOppId, ' Team Name ' + mrfTeamName + ', Product Name ' + mrfProductName + ' & Revenue Date ' + mrf.Revenue_Date__c.format());
                    }
                }
            }

            for(Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c mrf : newMRFs) {
                errorMessage = errorMessagebyOppId.get(mrf.Opportunity__c);
                if (errorMessage != null) {
                    oppsByOppId.get(mrf.Opportunity__c).addError(' No Budget record was found for MRF record(s) with ' + errorMessage + '\n' + ' [WE_MRFv3]');
                }
            }
```

At the moment, the line break `\n` in my addError message doesn't 'work', this is the error message that's displayed -

[image: error message]

*this message is not being displayed in a VisualForce page*

obviously it would be much easier to make sense of the message if each record's details were displayed on a new line. Can line breaks be included in error messages?

Comment: try this <br/>  -- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090A2IAI

Comment: @kurunve I get the unexpected token error if I use `+ errorMessage + <br/> + ' [WE_MRFv3]'` This isn't being used in a VisualForce page, if that makes a difference.

Comment: + errorMessage + '<br/>' + ...

Comment: `<br />` is an HTML tag, meaning it wouldn't need to be concatinated like you've done in your comment. It'd look more like `+ errorMessage + ' any text goes here.<br/>This is where the new line should start.'`

Comment: @kurunve @Poet if I use `& Revenue Date ' + mrf.Revenue_Date__c.format() + '<br/>');` there's still no line break and `<br/>` is displayed in the message's text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Salesforce by default escapes any html in the addError String. To work around this, use the addError method with additional 'escape' parameter at the end:

```
oppsByOppId.get(mrf.Opportunity__c).addError(' No Budget record was found for MRF record(s) with ' + errorMessage + '<br/>' + ' [WE_MRFv3]',false);
```

The above should at least put [WE_MRFv3] on a new line. If you want all the errors on separate lines, put `<br/>` in with each iteration of adding text to the message.

Documentation (including a security warning!) can be found here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError_2

Comment: In order to display each record's error on a separate line I'll need to change the location of the break but when using `errorMessagebyOppId.put(mrfOppId, existingMessage +  ' Team Name ' + mrfTeamName + ', Product Name ' + mrfProductName + ' & Revenue Date ' + mrf.Revenue_Date__c.format() + '<br/>');` the html markup is not rendered, it's displayed in the message's text. Can I escape the html markup in the string? In the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) it looks like this shouldn't be necessary but..

Comment: No it shouldn't, indeed. Are you sure you're still escaping html in the addError? Is the last line ([WE...) still on a new line?

Comment: That was it, I had removed the html from the addError section of the code so I also removed the escape, adding it back in got everything working. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad to be of help :-)